# Difference between let and have keywords in lean 4

Tags: lean

I noticed that both

```
#eval have x : Nat := 3 ; x*2
```

and

```
#eval let x : Nat := 3 ; x*2
```

work in the same way. Same goes when proving theorems.
Are those equivalent? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `let` "remembers" the definition and `have` forgets it.

So for example, the following works with `let` but not `have`.

```
example : {x : nat // x = 0} :=
let x := 0 in ⟨x, rfl⟩
```

In general `have` is usually used for proofs and `let` for everything else. In tactic mode you can use `dsimp [x]` to unfold the definition of `let x := ...`

Answer (score 2):

This is what `have` does

> Internally, the expression `have h : p := s; t` produces the term `(fun (h : p) => t) s`. In other words, `s` is a proof of `p`, `t` is a proof of the desired conclusion assuming `h : p`, and the two are combined by a lambda abstraction and application.

This is what `let` does

> The `let` construct is a stronger means of abbreviation, and there are expressions of the form `let a := t1; t2` that cannot be expressed as `(fun a => t2) t1`. As an exercise, try to understand why the definition of `foo` below type checks, but the definition of `bar` does not.

```
def foo := let a := Nat; fun x : a => x + 2
/-
  def bar := (fun a => fun x : a => x + 2) Nat
-/
```